# Newsletter signup for Mailchimp : Recaptcha not showing

Tags: recaptcha, mailchimp

Originally I use `Mailchimp` embed form for newsletter signup.
But it was not `reCAPTCHA` enabled. It worked well but few hours ago, I noticed large amount of spam signups at `Mailchimp`.

So I was going to add `reCAPTCHA` to my form to prevent bots. 
I go to the `Mailchimp -> Settings -> List` name and campaign defaults and I saw the checkbox for `reCAPTCHA` enabling as below.

[Mailchimp Enabling reCAPTCHA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tiwH.png)

I enabled it. The problem is that I cannot see `reCAPTCHA` box on the form. And I tested with several fake data and 
the result is everything worked well as before.

Could anybody help me? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Should I change code after when I enabled the reCAPTCHA?

Comment: did you get this to work? Running into the same problem now where the recaptcha isn't displaying on my embedded form.

Answer (score -1):

We started getting spam signups as well. It turns out the reason for that is that Mailchimp turned off double opt-in a few weeks ago. So I turned it back on and the spam signups stopped.

I would rather use reCaptcha than double opt-in but like you cannot get reCaptcha to work.

Comment: This is not an answer for my question.
So do you mean it's not possible to get the reCaptcha to work?